# Casting between SpannableStringBuilder and CharSequence

Tags: java, android, casting

```
TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.abc);
String rawString = "abcdefg";
SpannableStringBuilder ssb = new SpannableStringBuilder(rawString);
ssb.setSpan(new StyleSpan(android.graphics.Typeface.BOLD), 0, rawString.length(), Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
tv.setText(ssb);
CharSequence cs = tv.getText();
System.out.println(cs.getClass());
```

The output is "class android.text.SpannedString"

Why? I expect it to be "SpannableStringBuilder", my casting (`SpannableStringBuilder ssb_2 = (SpannableStringBuilder)cs;`) will give error for the example above.

Some more, the output will change to "SpannableString" if I set the buffer type of the text view to be `android:bufferType="spannable"`

Anyone know why?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**1.** Well the reason `(SpannableStringBuilder ssb_2 = (SpannableStringBuilder)cs;)` doesn't work is because `SpannableStringBuilder` implements `CharSequence`, meaning CharSequence does not know it can be casted to that. You can however do it the other way around. Does that make sense?

**CharSequence is a nothing/itself**

**SpannableStringBuilder is a**: *CharSequence, Spannable, Editable*, etc...

**2.** As for why `android:bufferType="spannable"` works, you are doing what I said above, the opposite. Since `SpannableString` implements `CharSequence`, it is now a child of it and therefore can be placed in `CharSequence`.

But anyways, the correct way to put your `CharSequence` in `SpannableStringBuilder` is by doing:

```
SpannableStringBuilder ssb_2 = SpannableStringBuilder(cs);
```

You might want to brush up on some polymorphism :) but you can see this in the Android docs on [SpannableStringBuilder's](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/SpannableStringBuilder.html#SpannableStringBuilder%28java.lang.CharSequence%29) constructor, or one of them at least.

---

**Update:**

From what I notice on what you are doing, what is the need to use `CharSequence`? Just leave the TextView as is, meaning its returned as a String. So doing something like this would be easier:

```
SpannableStringBuilder ssb_2 = SpannableStringBuilder(tv.getText());
```

Reason that works is because String implements CharSequence as well, meaning that it as well can be passed into the SpannableStringBuilder constructor as a `CharSequence`. Java does automatic casting in certain cases, including in that code right above.

Comment: Wow, this is indeed a brilliant way to do it, casting is too risky. I will cast it is because I want to call the function setSpan that exist in SpannableStringBuilder but not CharSequence.

Comment: Glad to have helped. Cheers :)